I have two identical LaTeX files, with different file names. Only one yields "undefined references." Why is this happening?
I have been trying to get extremely basic LaTeX files out with Chicago formatting, and so far, everything has either not worked or just provided new errors. This is one such case. You can see my previous efforts in this thread.
I finally had gotten references to work with biblatex/biber exporting with xelatex, and I decided I wanted to change the file name to more accurately reflect what it was: a text Chicago LaTeX article. Thus, the initial file name was Test LaTeX Article.tex and the renamed version was Test Chicago LaTeX Article.tex. When I renamed the file, suddenly my references were all broken, despite not changing anything in the content of either file.
Here's an example of one of the errors: LaTeX Warning: Citation 'wilesBehavioralSink2011' on page 2 undefined on input  line 44.
I have no idea what is going on and am pretty fed up with this right now. I am going to take a break from working on this and hopefully someone can help. Thanks!

Welcome to TeX.SE. After renaming the tex file, did you run a full recompile cycle on it, i.e., LaTeX - biber- LaTeX? Or did you merely run LaTeX on it? Please advise.

Hello. I have both tried running org-latex-export-to-pdf (I am coming from Emacs/org-mode), which first creates a .tex file and then attempts to export it to a PDF (I am using xelatex). I am not sure of the steps required to use biber. I have looked online, but have not found a clear answer. Here is how I think it should work:

latex xyz.tex
pdflatex xyz.tex
biber xyz.bcf
xelatex xyz.tex
This seems like a lot of steps—is this accurate? If so, is there a way to streamline it?


I don't know much about emacs and org mode. What is clearly wrong is that all your compilation steps must use the same engine; also note that you might need to compile twice after biber. So, a correct sequence would be: 1. pdflatex xyz, 2. biber xyz, 3. pdflatex xyz, 4. pdflatex xyz. Notice that you do not need the extensions.

Okay, thank you, that helps a lot. I don't expect you to know much about Emacs, and I have made questions on the appropriate site for issues directly regarding it and this issue. I just thought I should bring it up in case it was relevant. I prefer xelatex, so would a valid sequence look like this? 2. xelatex xyz 2. biber xyz 3. xelatex xyz (4.) xelatex xyz

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Chiaroscuro - Yes, xelatex xyz - biber xyz - xelatex xyz represents a complete recompile cycle.

Okay, thank you. I have resolved this issue both inside and outside of Emacs. You can put your suggestions as the answer if you wish.

(I'm just summarizing the essence of some of the previously-posted comments, so that this query can be considered to have received a valid answer.)
When compiling a LaTeX document that contains a bibliography generated by an external program such as bibtex or biber, it's necessary to (re)run bibtex or biber whenever the \cite commands change.

This condition also applies when one creates a brand-new copy of an existing tex file, unless one also makes suitable copies of all associated auxiliary files -- which would not appear to be the case here.

So, while the OP may have copied abc.tex to abc-new.tex, no copies of files such as abc.aux and abc.bbl were made. That's why it's necessary to also run biber: to (re)create the needed auxiliary files.


If BibTeX (and, presumably, a citation management package such as natbib) as well as pdflatex are in use, a full recompile cycle performed on a LaTeX document named, say, xyz.tex consists of running
   pdflatex xyz - bibtex xyz - pdflatex xyz - pdflatex xyz

Or, if biber (and biblatex) as well as xelatex are in use, a full recompile cycle consists of running
   xelatex xyz - biber xyz - xelatex xyz

Either way, there's no need to specify any filename extensions.

I understand this is just a summary of the comments, but I guess it doesn't really/explicitly address the question why the references stop working when the filename is changed on a file that has been compiled before (i.e., because renaming the .tex file creates a mismatch with the previously compiled bibliography files). Maybe you can add some explanation on this point?

@Marijn - Thanks for this suggestion. I've edited my answer to provide some more information.
